# Ubuntu 18.04 external screen freezes when connected to hdmi

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer Aspire V Nitro 17. It is all worked fine until i made an updgarde via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now when ever I connect my laptop to the external monitor from AOC, my external screen shows my desktop but the image is not moving or doing anything I press with my mouse. I only can move my mouse. When I then plug the external screen of my laptop and work with the build in display. I see what I just pressed.
So I can't use my external screen.
Can somebody please help me?
Thanks already!
The device has a NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1060 graphics card...

Comment: Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: I think so, how do you check that ?

Comment: Try reading through these. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-update-the-drivers-in-ubuntu https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/ https://www.howtogeek.com/242045/how-to-get-the-latest-nvidia-amd-or-intel-graphics-drivers-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes, I am using the newest drivers the nvidia 440

Comment: Is that command right? `sudo apt-het upgrade`? Shouldn't it be `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3` and reboot.

Comment: okay, i tried that but now the screen isn't getting recognized ;)

Comment: Then it is probably something wrong with the screen. Do you have another screen?